# Oracle merge into statement

Tags: oracle, insert, merge

Trying to insert lists from python into an Oracle database. I want to insert 4 pieces of data from each list into Oracle and if 3 of the Data entries match I want to update. If they don't match I want to insert.

```
Equip_ID
Parameter_Name
Parameter_Value
Customer
```

So for this one entry if the Equip_ID, Parameter_Name, and Customer match an entry already in the DB then I want to update the Parameter Value. If they don't match then I want to insert all of the data into the DB. This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
MERGE INTO dbName.tableName 
  USING '26522931','Customer','Para001','99999'
  ON (tableName.EQUIPMENT_NODE_ID = '26522931' AND tableName.STREAM_NAME = 'Customer' AND tableName.PARAMETER_NAME = 'Para000')
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tableName.PARAMETER_VALUE = '99999'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (EQUIPMENT_NODE_ID,STREAM_NAME,PARAMETER_NAME,PARAMETER_VALUE) VALUES('26522931','Customer','Para000','99999')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you want something like this.  You'll need to select the data from DUAL if you don't have some other table to use as the source.

```
MERGE INTO dbName.tableName 
  USING (select '26522931' equipment_node_id,
                'Customer' stream_name,
                'Para001'  parameter_name,
                '99999'    parameter_value
            from dual) src
  ON (tableName.EQUIPMENT_NODE_ID = src.EQUIPMENT_NODE_ID  
  AND tableName.STREAM_NAME = src.STREAM_NAME  
  AND tableName.PARAMETER_NAME = src.PARAMETER_NAME )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tableName.PARAMETER_VALUE = src.parameter_value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (EQUIPMENT_NODE_ID,
          STREAM_NAME,
          PARAMETER_NAME,
          PARAMETER_VALUE) 
    VALUES(src.EQUIPMENT_NODE_ID,
           src.STREAM_NAME,
           src.PARAMETER_NAME,
           src.PARAMETER_VALUE)
```